# How to use Jquery how to change the aria-expanded="false" part of a dom element (Bootstrap)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following element:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
```

I want to use jquery (or just javascript would work) to alter the aria-expanded field to toggle it between true and false.

How would I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not adding another answer even though it is not exactly a duplicate of the existing ones. But if you wish to do this using plain JS, you can use `el.setAttribute("aria-expanded", true);` where `el` is the element which can obtained using `getElementById` or `querySelector` or `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can use [.attr()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp) as a part of however you plan to toggle it:

```
$("button").attr("aria-expanded","true");
```

Comment: What about using `.prop` and having `$("button").prop('aria-expanded', true)`? I read that `.attr` is applicable to jQuery v1.5 and below, while `.prop` is available for jQuery v1.6 and above.

Comment: For some reason, `$(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').prop('aria-expanded', 'true')` isn't working for me in this case, while `attr()` does. I'm using jquery v3.2.1

Answer (score 2):

Since the question asked for either jQuery *or* vanilla JS, here's an answer with vanilla JS.

I've added some CSS to the demo below to change the button's font color to red when its `aria-expanded` is set to `true`

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  button.ariaExpanded = !JSON.parse(button.ariaExpanded);
})
```

```css
button[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" aria-expanded="false">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `prop` but then as it is property name, change it to `ariaExpanded`. So it will be:

```
$("button").prop("ariaExpanded", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Toggle class based on an element's click. aria-expanded value is mentioned after a click

```
$("#navbar-btn-icon").click(function(e) {
  var menuItem = $(this);

  if (menuItem.attr("aria-expanded") === "true") {
    $(".navbar-toggler-icon").addClass('clicked');
  }
  else if (menuItem.attr("aria-expanded") === "false") {
    $(".navbar-toggler-icon").removeClass('clicked');
  }

});
```

Add close button icon in CSS. Changes on click

```
.navbar-toggler-icon.clicked{
    background-image: url("close-icon.png");
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}
```